# Socket.IO Sign In

Tags: node.js, socket.io

So I have an application which uses Socket.IO, and the client connects to the Socket.IO server using a token generated by the web server when the client made a request. This should mean that they Socket.IO connection is now secure for this user.

I was wondering if it was practical to do user authentication (signing in/out) through Socket.IO alone meaning no POST. The client would send send an event like io.emit('authenticate', { ... sign in data ... }); and the Socket.IO would check the credentials and if it was verified, it would manually set the session data through the session store.

Is this way of doing this secure, or should the traditional POST for signing in/out still be used?

Answer (score 0):

Doing it via Socket.IO is just as secure as an HTTP POST simply due to the fact that an HTTP POST has zero security built into it. You need to make sure that this process is secure and neither HTTP POST nor Socket.IO will help you with that at all.